# Next.js - Can I configure multiple image hostnames in next.config.js?

Tags: next.js

**I write this code below in my next.config.js**

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: [
          'images.unsplash.com',
          'hydeparkwinterwonderland.com',
          'wembleypark.com']
      },
    ]
  }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

**but it throw an error like this:**

```
- The value at .images.remotePatterns[0].hostname must be a string but it was an array.

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-next-config
```

```
Error: Invalid images.remotePatterns values:
{"protocol":"https","hostname":["images.unsplash.com","hydeparkwinterwonderland.com","wembleypark.com"]}

remotePatterns value must follow format { protocol: 'https', hostname: 'example.com', port: '', pathname: '/imgs/**' }.
See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-images-config
```

looking for an answer, I'm a newbie please be patient with me

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`hostname` only allows a single value, so you cannot pass an array of host names. Instead of that, you can have multiple items for host names in `remotePatterns`.

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'images.unsplash.com'
      },
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'hydeparkwinterwonderland.com'
      },
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'wembleypark.com'
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

Or less duplicated code with `map`

```js
const hostnames = [
          'images.unsplash.com',
          'hydeparkwinterwonderland.com',
          'wembleypark.com']

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    remotePatterns: hostnames.map(hostname => ({
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname
    }))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you are trying to configure multiple remote domains but nextjs doesn't allow you to specify `hostname` as an array (as the name stated it's `hostname`), so answer your original questions you need to tweak the code as below.

```
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'images.unsplash.com'
      },
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'hydeparkwinterwonderland.com'
      },
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'wembleypark.com'
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

Basically `remotePatters` accept an array of object and each object denote one pattern so you need to create multiple patterns for the different domain name.